# Reload a page with jQuery

Tags: jquery, reload

I created a page that will take a users input and then compare the input with a word. The idea is that the user has 6 chances to guess the word. If the user guesses the word or ran out of guesses the button clicked will change from ***Guess*** to ***Start a New Game***. All that I got right.

The idea is then that the user will click the **Start a Game** button and the page will reset to original values, here is where I am having a problem. My button will change to the new value and the new id, but when I click the button the game still plays and then when I click it again and it does reset. Why is it not resting at the first click?

Here is how the part of the function looks

```
else if (theGuess.toLowerCase() == magicWord.toLowerCase()) 
{
    //The user guesses the correct word
    $("input[type=text]").ready(function () { $("#guestGuess").addClass("unblur"); });
    $("input[type=submit]").val("Start a New Game");
    $("input[type=submit]").attr("id","startNew");
$('#guestGuess').val('');
$('#startNew').click(function() {
        location.reload();
});
magicWordResult = "Your guess was " + theGuess + "! Nice going!";
//document.writeln("Your guess was: " + guestGuess + "\nand the magic word is " + magicWord);
}
```

You can find the whole code here http://liveweave.com/psAsxh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it. Here is how I was able to make it run properly:

- When the user ran out of guesses or guess the correct work the `id` of the submit button gets changed to `startNew`
- Then I added a double condition to the empty text check where the code will check if the text box is empty but also the code will check if the `id` for the submit button is `guestGuess`.

That is where I was having issues because when I was clicking an empty window that part of the code was running as well.

I updated the code here http://liveweave.com/SZDKHz

Thank you so much for all the help.

Comment: Glad you fixed it on your own - minor detail just to be sure: you'll fix the part with the counter accordingly? Currently when you start a new game it starts to count down from 0 (e.g. 2nd game 2nd wrong guess value -2 and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Just use location.reload(true) - this will cause the page to reload from server instead from cache. For reference:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload

Update: Checked your game and still looking about the lines spoiling the result. I've just added console.log for the functions called on clicking `#guess` and `#startNew`, and the result is: after max guesses the `#startNew` function is called, but every next click calls both functions.
There's a very easy (lazy?) approach to fix it without having to bother why the current code is not working - just add a 2nd button for `#startNew`, so instead of changing the functionality of a single button you would just change the visibility of two buttons.
A different approach would be to call only **one** function on click without changing the button's id and have the function adjusted to handle a parameter - like `function handleButton (value) {... }` - and for the guesses it just handles the guess-part of the game, for the start-new it handles the start-new part  - just calling `handleButton("guess")` and `handleButton("new")`. As you already coded this game I guess you can handle that ;)

Comment: Even if I add the location.reload(true) I still have to click twice on the button for it to reload. I don't think my page is doing it from the cache.

Comment: Ok, I've just played your game twice and I think I know what you mean. Will take a look at the code, looks like it has something to do how you bind / unbind the click() event for the submit.

Comment: np, I just updated the answer and maybe will have a look at the current code tomorrow (as it's getting late here) to check if it's possible to switch between diff click()-events for an id-changed button; it's possible that this is a problematic approach that's not needed

Answer (score 0):

I always used location.href = location.href, to refresh, but its pure JavaScript rather than jquery.